# Laravel Comment Section Plug-in

Tags: php, sublimetext3

In Laravel, I saw a lot these pre-made comments look like this :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
```

Does anybody know what is that plug-in call ? I want to install it in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a plugin for that type of comments , you will need to add a `code snippet` for that in your editor and assign some shortcut to that snippet whenever you need to add that comment , then you can use that shortcut to insert the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you IDE supports code snippets or templates you can add your own template to it.

In PHPStorm it called `Live Templates`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try look for that in Sublime Text 3.